# Scrapy LinkExtractor cannot extract links with href of mailto:

Tags: python, hyperlink, scrapy

I'm using the LinkExtractor class to extract all the links from a page

```
for link in LinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response):
    print link.url
```

This prints all the URLs from the page. But I can't seem to get the links that have href equal to a mailto: link. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Mail</a>
```

Do I need to pass some argument to LinkExtractor to make it grab the links with mailto: ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `LinkExtractor` to get the urls you need, simply use xpath with the response object.

```
all_links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
```

`LinkExtractor` focuses on getting links to follow, so that's why it avoids `mailto` links by default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The reason why I'm using LinkExtractor is because I want to extract links that do not belong to a particular domain, in my case I want to grab all the external links. So, what I'm doing is ` LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response)` . Is there a way in which I can achieve this using your method?

Comment: if you definitely want to use LinkExtractor, maybe @GHajba solution could help. but you could just iterate the links you have and get the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, BeautifulSoup would be an alternative to use.

But this won't answer your question. The cause for your problem is that LxmlLinkExtractor (this is the one which is the default LinkExtractor in scrapy) has a filtering (because it extends FilteringLinkExtractor) and this has a lambda for valid URLs and filters them. This expression is the following:

```
_is_valid_url = lambda url: url.split('://', 1)[0] in {'http', 'https', 'file'}
```

As you can see, `mailto` is not valid in this case.

You could write your own implementation where you allow `mailto` as a valid URL too -- however you have to take care because LinkExtractors automatically create a `Request` and call the URLs which they get so you would end up with exceptions for email addresses.

If you want to gather the email addresses create another parser function where you extract them from the site -- and let LinkExtractor go through the whole website with all its internal links.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using BeautifulSoup to accomplish this task?

```
r = requests.get( url, params )

soup = BeautifulSoup( r.text, 'html.parser' )

#Getting all h3 tags with class 'r'
h3tags = soup.find_all( 'h3', class_='r' )

for h3 in h3tags:
```

Comment: Because I have tens of thousands of pages to crawl and BeautifulSoup is quite slow.

Comment: Well that's true. I've scrapped almost 100,000 pages, I tried other ways like googleAPI and JSON etc but google has limit to not allow anyone to scrap more than 100 pages, but using requests and BeautifulSoup I scrapped almost 100,000 pages. But yes its slow